# Expressing a permutation as a product of transpositions

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

Express $(123) \in S_3$ as the product of four transpositions $$(123) = \tau_1\tau_2\tau_3\tau_4$$ such that $\tau_i \neq \tau_{i+1}$ for $i = 1,2,3$.

I am confused as to how I should approach this question. In the examples from lectures we have gone over examples where there are 2 variables but not only one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $(123)=(132)(132)$ and $(132)=(23)(31)$.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your own question like this, especially after it has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

$(1 2 3) = (2 3) (3 1) (2 3) (3 1)$